# Difference between the Facade, Proxy, Adapter and Decorator design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, proxy, adapter, decorator, facade

What is the difference between the *Facade*, *Proxy*, *Adapter*, and *Decorator* design patterns?

From a generic point of view, such patterns seem to do the same thing, that is: **wrap an API and provide access to it**.

*How to distinguish these patterns?

How to discern when one pattern suits more than the others?*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618779/differences-between-proxy-and-decorator-pattern/

Comment: @gavenkoa the other question is only about proxy and decorator

Comment: Incredible as some closed question reveal themselves so useful.

Answer (score 341, accepted):

**Adapter** adapts a given class/object to a new interface. In the case of the former, multiple inheritance is typically employed. In the latter case, the object is wrapped by a conforming adapter object and passed around. The problem we are solving here is that of *non-compatible interfaces*.

**Facade** is more like a simple gateway to a complicated set of functionality. You make a black-box for your clients to worry less i.e. *make interfaces simpler*.

**Proxy** provides the same interface as the proxied-for class and typically does some housekeeping stuff on its own. (So instead of making multiple copies of a heavy object `X` you make copies of a lightweight proxy `P` which in turn manages `X` and translates your calls as required.) You are solving the problem of the client from having to *manage a heavy and/or complex object*.

**Decorator** is used to add more gunpowder to your objects (note the term objects -- you typically decorate objects dynamically at runtime). You do not hide/impair the existing interfaces of the object but *simply extend it at runtime*.

Now that you have decorator involved, you will probably want to know why the emphasis on the word object -- some languages (like Java) simply don't allow virtual inheritance (i.e. multiple inheritance as C++ does) to allow you to accomplish this at compile time.

Since we have dragged in multiple inheritances (and the dreaded diamond) you will look out for *mixins* -- which are *ordered linear chaining of interfaces* to get around the problems of multiple inheritance. However, mixins don't mix that well. And we end up with *traits* -- yes those *stateless little blobs of behavior* that you see pop-up all the time in template parameters in C++. Traits try to address the issues of composition and decomposition of behavior in an elegant manner while not going either for multiple inheritances or ordered chaining.

Comment: HTH! I have tried to put in as much as I can without being too vague. Excuse my inability to do better. I have read (PhD dissertation) papers on traits alone. My knowledge therefore is rather limited and I ain't good enough to fit in all patterns in this space ;)

Comment: You anticipated a future question about mixins and traits but I haven't seen them yet !

Comment: A good comparison link (via wikipedia) for the first three (the Decorator being quite different): 
[NetObjectives](http://www.netobjectivestest.com/PatternRepository/index.php?title=AdapterVersusProxyVersusFacadePatternComparison)

Comment: @Liviu Your link is dead. I assume you were originally pointing [there](http://www.netobjectives.com/resources/net-objectives-pattern-repository), but the content now seems to be behind a login.

Comment: @Sheljohn  Link updated :p :
A good comparison link (via wikipedia) for the first three (the Decorator being quite different)
[NetObjectives](http://www.netobjectives.com/PatternRepository/index.php?title=AdapterVersusProxyVersusFacadePatternComparison) (Retreiveing text, see "betweem": "One of the more frequent questions I get in class is "what's the difference betweem Adapter, Proxy, and Facade? They really seem the same to me".)

Answer (score 19):

**Facade**

You could use a facade, for example, to make calls to an API easier. Take a look at [this](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/remoteFacade.html) example of a remote facade. The idea here is that the full implementation of the code on the server is hidden away from the client. The client calls 1 API method which, in turn, can make 1 or more API calls on the server.

**Adapter**

A good example of this can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), on Wikipedia. A client object `Source` would like to call a method on another object `Target`, but that other object's interface differs to what the client is expecting.

Enter the adapter object.

It can take a call from the `Source` object and, behind the scenes, call the `Target` method which should be used.

`Source->CallMethodAOnTarget() ---< Adaptor.CallMethodAOnTarget() this calls ---> Target.MethodWithDifferentSignatureAndName(int i)`

As for Proxy, I don't have any experience of this design pattern.