# why does proxy pattern uses the realSubject class instead of composing the Subject interface

Tags: design-patterns

The two patterns' uml shotted from book *Design Patterns Elements of Resuable Object-Oriented Software* are listed below:

Proxy pattern uml :

[image]

Decorator pattern uml:

[image]

my question is why does proxy pattern **use** the *realSubject* class instead of **composing** the *Subject* interface just like the decorator pattern does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proxy Design Pattern: Association to the Interface or to RealSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65740160/proxy-design-pattern-association-to-the-interface-or-to-realsubject) A Proxy may instantiate its RealSubject, and therefore would require a concrete dependency.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I got the matched answer from the link in side your link. Using relation means the proxy manages the delegatee by itself while composition means the delegatee is managed by the client. In other words, the decorator knows little about the delegatee while the proxy knows more. Right?

Comment: That can be the case, but not always. As I describe in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60478875/1371329) quoting the GoF book, composition is not the relationship that distinguishes between these two patterns.